# Как узнать, откуда был вызван метод?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2015

Есть громоздкий код, выполняю его отладку. Есть метод, который часто вызывается из разных мест. Можно ли по точке останова узнать, откуда он был вызван? Или может можно вернуться назад по шагам?

Comment: А почему бы не заглянуть в окошко stack trace?

Comment: Панель Call Stack

Comment: Call Stack, а не Stack Trace, конечно же.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Посмотреть откуда был вызван метод можно в окне Debug → Windows → Call Stack

В нем же можно просмотреть значения локальных переменных в вызывающих методах. И даже поставить брекпойнт на момент возврата в вызывающий метод - например, выбрав Main на скриншоте и нажав F9 (прямо в этом окне, а не в исходнике Main).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Отмотать назад" тоже можно.

Но только в Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 при заранее влюченной опции сборки информации о вызовах (Tools/Options/IntelliTrace/events and call information)

Debug → Windows → IntelliTrace Calls:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 21):

Дополнение к другим ответам: Если вы не хотите каждый раз останавливать программу, попробуйте просто залогировать строку

```
new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString();
```

Например,

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString());
```

распечатает текущий стек в окно отладки Output.

Comment: @минусатор: Надеюсь, вам не составит труда откомментировать вашу оценку.

Answer (score 19):

В дополнение к сказанному, можно создать специальный метод для трассировки, вложить его во все диагностируемые методы. Атрибут `CallerMemberName` (.NET 4.5) поможет определить вызывающий метод.

Пример с MSDN:

```
public void DoProcessing()
{
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");
}

public void TraceMessage(string message,
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);
}

// Sample Output:
//  message: Something happened.
//  member name: DoProcessing
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs
//  source line number: 31
```

p.s. так же можно просто добавить нужные атрибуты в параметры диагностируемого метода, и передавать их в метод трассирови, либо сразу выводить через `System.Diagnostics.Debug` или `System.Diagnostics.Trace`.